# Why doesn't the compiler show an error with these return types?

Tags: c++, function, compiler-errors, return-type

Running a default installation of Ubuntu 11.10 with the latest version of NetBeans. I have something similar to the following:

```
class MyClass {
    public:
        Type1 RunAlgo();
    private:
        Type2 Run();
}

Type1 MyClass::RunAlgo() {
    //additional code
    return Run();
}

Type2 Run() {
    //additional code
    Type2 obj;
    return obj;
}
```

Type1 and Type2 are completely unrelated. I came upon this by making a typo in the return type when I was writing the Run() method and was amazed that it compiled. I am just wondering why this does not return an error and just compiles fine? What am I missing?

EDIT: New sample. This does generate an error as a stand alone project. Can't seem to spot why the real project would indeed compile.

```
class Node { };

//only difference here is that in my code I have a custom comparer
typedef map<Node*, map<Node*, double> > Network; 

class HMM {
    Network _network;
};

class Algorithm {
    public:
        HMM RunAlgo();
    private:
        Network _network;
        Network Run();
};

HMM Algorithm::RunAlgo() {
    return Run();
}

Network Algorithm::Run() {
    return _network;
}
```

EDIT2:

I apologize for my badly formulated question and example. I will be more careful in the future about examples. I've been working for a bit over 10 hours and lost focus. The following example reproduces my case:

```
#include <map>

using std::map;

class Node {

};

typedef map<Node*, map<Node*, double> > Network;

class HMM {
    public:
        HMM(const Network& network) {};
    Network _network;
};


class TestClass {
    public:
        HMM RunAlgo(int x, int y);
    private:
        Network _network;
        Network Run();
};

HMM TestClass::RunAlgo(int x, int y) {
    return Run();
}

Network TestClass::Run() {
    return _network;
}
```

After adding that specific constructor to the HMM class it compiles without problems. I didn't know this could be done as this is the first time I encounter this case. Again I apologize if I wasted your time and I appreciate you trying to help me.

Comment: Are "some parameters" and "some params" the typo? Or the missing semicolon? Are they part of the question? Please present your _real_ testcase so that we don't have to waste our precious time guessing.

Comment: My mistake. Will edit out the some parameters. They are not important to the case. I apologize for the confusion.

Comment: Maybe `Type1` and `Type2` aren't as unrelated as you think. Please post their declarations (at least their constructors & assignment operators)

Comment: are you actually calling and using RunAlgo(...)?

Comment: @Morat: at least try your samples. You're missing `;` at the end of the class declarations. And even with that, GCC rejects the code: `error: conversion from ‘Network’ to non-scalar type ‘HMM’ requested`.

Answer (score 1):

After fixing the mistakes in your non-testcase, [*my* compiler does error out](http://codepad.org/XZikftyY).

Your statement that `Type1` and `Type2` are unrelated must be false.

Take care on a real testcase next time.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't show your actual code; the example you gave us don't compile (GCC 4.6 on Debian/Sid/AMD64)

```
% g++ -Wall exmorat.cc 
exmorat.cc:3:9: error: 'Type1' does not name a type
exmorat.cc:5:9: error: 'Type2' does not name a type
exmorat.cc:8:7: error: expected initializer before 'MyClass'
```

But what you describes may happen when you have conversions or casting involved. You should show your actual code (or a simplified code which exhibits the symptoms) to get real help.

Comment: He/she should already be working with a simplified piece of code (or a "testcase") as part of the basic fundamentals of _debugging_.

Comment: The classes are too big to be post them here. I tried reproducing this scenario with a simplified version of the code but in that case it does produce an error. I can't seem to see any noticeable difference between the two scenarios.